# MATLAB function output ans unwanted

Tags: matlab, function

I have a function

```
function [ obsTime, obsWDIR, obsWSPD, obsSWH, obsMWD ] = readObsC(obsFile, endTime)
```

that when I run it, it gives an output of a huge array `ans`, which is the same array as `obsTime`. But `obsTime`, `obsWDIR`, `obsWSPD`, etc. don't display. Not a single line of code is supposed to display `ans`.

When I'm in debugging mode, I run the code and stop it at the very last line, and it doesn't give an output `ans`. Only when I hit 'step' twice and the function ends, does the `ans` output appear.

Everything in the function has semicolons.

Why does `ans` appear? Where are my other outputs?

Comment: Or, when you call your output function, make sure you assign variables to each of the possible outputs.  So at the command line type `>>[ obsTime, obsWDIR, obsWSPD, obsSWH, obsMWD ] = readObsC(obsFile, endTime);`.  This way, all of your outputs are assigned to variables in the workspace.  If you just call the function without defining the outputs, then by default only the first output is returned (and so displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function definition, you name the formal input and output arguments.  That determines the name which these arguments will use within the function.

The function has its own environment, and variable names inside the function are completely independent of variable names outside the function, unless you use `global` or `evalin('caller')`.

You have to provide actual input and output arguments at the time of the call, which determines how the code outside the function refers to those same arguments.  There is no automatic passing of arguments simply because the names match!  The only automatic thing is that if you don't specify the actual output arguments, the first actual output argument will be `ans` and the rest are discarded.

You could have figured this out if you simply read the [MATLAB documentation for `ans`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ans.html):

> The MATLAB® software creates the ans variable automatically when you specify no output argument.

Comment: So, how would I change the formal output arguments to actual output arguments?  Without pasting [ obsTime, obsWDIR, obsWSPD, obsSWH, obsMWD ] = readObsC(obsFile, endTime); into the command line. I just want to run the program (hit F5, really) and have it give me those arrays and no ans array.

Comment: @Crystalh321: Maybe what you really want is a script?  Scripts don't have their own environment, any variables they assign appear in your workspace (or the function that calls the script, if not from the command line)

Comment: Um, how do I convert a function to a script? Simply deleting the word function will give an error. (This is my fourth day of using MATLAB.)

Comment: Just comment out that entire top line.  You'll no longer provide arguments when you call it, the inputs have to be stored in workspace variables by the right name beforehand, and all created variables (including but not limited to outputs) will be in the workspace after the script runs.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The function declaration specifies the return values, but when you call it, you don't specify anywhere for the output to go. When you call something on the command line, the output is always defaulted to `ans` unless you assign a variable to the output of the function when you call it.

I defined a simple function called `myfunc` as:

```
function [one,two,three,four] = myfunc(value1,value2)
```

Ex, using workspace variables (denoted ws_) to capture function output:

```
>> [ws_one,ws_two,ws_three,ws_four] = myfunc(1,2)
```

prints:

```
ws_one =

     1


ws_two =

     2


ws_three =

     1


ws_four =

     2
```

Comment: You should use different names for the formal and actual outputs to highlight what is going on.